# Datatype convert problem

Tags: entity-framework-4, wcf-ria-services

In a DB, I have a SP return a bit result, like:

```
declare @temp bit; 
--......
return @temp;
```

In EF, I imported this SP as a function and return scarlars Boolean.
In domain service I called this function as:

```
public bool CallSP()
{
    var result =  this.ObjectContext.MySp();
    return (bool)result;
}
```

Then got this error:

```
Cannot convert type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectResult<bool?>' to 'bool'
```

How do I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public bool? CallSP()
{
     var result =  this.ObjectContext.MySp();
     return (bool?)result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public bool? CallSP()
{
     var result =  this.ObjectContext.MySp().First();
     return (bool?)result;
}
```